# password authentication in Client server model in C

Tags: c, client-server

I am trying to authenticate client using a password and if the client enters different password he should be again asked to re-enter the password
Following is my server code:

```
    while (1) {         
        printf("Expecting the pass\n");
        ret = recv(sock, pass, sizeof(pass), 0);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("Error receiving message");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            pass[strlen(pass) - 1] = '\0';
            printf("Password received %s of length %d\n", pass, strlen(pass));
        }
        printf("Received\n");
        if (strcmp("Abhishek", pass) == 0) {
            printf("Password entered is correct\n");
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "CORRECT");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Incorrect Password %s\n", pass);
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "I");
        }
        printf("SENDING : %s\n",buffer);
        ret = send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("Error sending message");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

And client side code is :

```
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter the password :");
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
        buf[ret] = '\0';
        ret = send(sockid, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("Error sending message");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            printf("Password sent\n");
        }
        memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf));
        ret = recv(sockid, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        printf("RECEIVED %s\n", buf);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("Error receiving message");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (buf[0] != 'I') {
            break;
        }
    }
```

When I execute them in different windows, I can see at server side:

```
Asking for password authentication
Expecting the pass
```

At client side:

```
Start the Admin Dialogue
Enter the password :
```

Now when I enter password in client window, it says:

```
Password sent
```

but Server is still at

```
Expecting the pass
```

Can somebody help me with that I am new to this concept

Comment: According to the question, the client says "Password sent", but you don't show that as part of the client side output. Does it or doesn't it?

Comment: WTF is this: 'pass[strlen(pass)-1]='\0';' ??  'ret', the value returned by recv(), is the ONLY reliable indication of how many bytes have been loaded into the buffer.

Comment: When I am entering the password it takes \n as an input too that is why to overwrite it

Comment: You cannot use safely use strlen() on a buffer that is not guaranteed NULL-terminated.

Comment: Classic socket bug in the above code. You need to check for partial data from `recv`. Call `recv` in a loop until you have the sufficient number of bytes of the message sent.  Or use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a complete function: definitions for the arrays and various variables are missing. Are `pass` and `buf` indeed defined an arrays?

You are not sending the `'\0'` terminators. The message recv'd on the client side is not null terminated. `strlen(pass)` invokes undefined behavior.  Unlikely to be the cause of your problem, but a significant bug nonetheless.

You need some kind of protocol to determine in the server and in the client when a complete message has been received.  You should either use `'\n'` as an end of message indicator or possibly a `'\0'`.

Here is how you would force null termination on the server side:

```
    printf("Expecting the pass\n");
    ret = recv(sock, pass, sizeof(pass) - 1, 0);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("Error receiving message");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        pass[ret] = '\0';
        if (ret > 0 && pass[ret - 1] == '\n')
            pass[--ret] = '\0';
        printf("Password received %s of length %d\n", pass, ret);
    }
```

But this is not sufficient to ensure that the full message has been received by the server, you really should recv until you get a linefeed, or some sort of protocol indicating a complete message.

On the client side, `buf[ret] = '\0';` seems useless and potentially risky.

Comment: That will prevent the missing-NULL UB, but will not fix the other problem of assuming that TCP can transfer messages longer than one byte without an additional protocol.

Comment: Ok, But that does not solve the server stuck problem

Comment: @MartinJames:  That's true, the OP should wrap his sockets in FILE  streams and read and write one full line at a time.

Comment: Also, 'pass[ret] = '\0';' will write out-of-bounds if the password fills the buffer, (OK, unlikely, but for completeness:).

Comment: Still did not get what is the error in the program??

Comment: @AbhishekGangwar your code is just riddled with misuse of NULL-terminated char arrays and other errors. chqrlie has already pointed some out, eg. 'buf[ret] = '\0';' where 'ret' seems to be uninitialized.   You should spend a lot of time going through your code, fixing all the classes of errors already pointed out and retesting.  If you still have problems, post another question with your test/debug results and all relevant data declarations to avoid continual, and wasteful, prompting.